# Assembly 'system.net.http, version=4.0.0.0' was not found in the SQL catalog

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB assembly with CLR functions and and DB project which referenced on DB assembly. When I trying to execute publishing query I have an error:

> Assembly 'system.net.http, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' was not found in the SQL catalog.

But in my DB assembly I have a reference to system.net.http, version=4.0.0.0

[image: system.net.http]
[image: system.net.http 4]

[image: error]

What's the problem?

Comment: That you are trying to make HTTP calls from inside the database resulting in huge delays and performance degradation ? If you want to make HTTP calls make them *outside* the database. In any case, that code will raise warning or not even run in the latest SQL Server versions

Comment: In any case, different SQL Server versions use different .NET runtimes. What the error says is that the *target* server doesn't have that library installed. For example, SQL Server 2008 R2 uses .NET 2.0 so SQLCLR functions it can't use 4.0 libraries

Comment: why do we need exactly 4.0.0.0 version?  P.S. Sorry for my question, It's a new project for me and I am new in SQL

Comment: Aside from the version difference, by default you will still not be able to load `System.Net.Http`, as it is not one of the system assemblies SQL Server supports. It has a small, pre-approved list of assemblies that it's sure won't destabilize the server and `System.Net.Http` is not on them. You would need to add it separately before this has any chance of working. See Solomon Rutzky's [article on the matter](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/119429/).

Comment: A much better approach to this is to not stuff the CLR code for HTTP calls inside SQL Server itself, if at all possible. It makes troubleshooting and fixing issues with performance and connectivity much harder than when you'd use separate client code. There is really no good reason to do this that I can think of -- not even performance, since the overhead of HTTP would dwarf any overhead of communication between SQL Server and a client app. Look into things like Service Broker and Integration Services for interoperating with web-based services.